# How to include all scripts of a directory into the current shell session?

Tags: bash

I have a directory that contains some script files:

```
/scripts
    api.sh
    time.sh
    certificate.sh
    docker.sh
    nginx.sh
    wifi.sh
    ...
```

These scripts are not commands. They just contain some functions in them. Thus I can't add `/script` to the `$PATH` and run them. For example, `api.sh` has this content:

```
function isApi()
{
   # body
}

function resetApi()
{
   # body
}

function testDatabase()
{
   # body
}
```

I need to include them in the current session and then call their functions.

If I include them one by one using `. /scripts/x.sh` I can use their functions.

But when I run a `loadScripts.sh` bash script to load them all, it won't work:

```
find /scripts -mindepth 1 |
while read scriptFile;
do
    echo $scriptFile
    source $scriptFile
done
```

How can I include all scripts of a directory in the current session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
for script in scripts/*.sh; do
  . "$script"
done
```

The `.` special sh builtin tells the shell to evaluate the code in the supplied file. csh has `source` for a similar command, some shells including `bash` support both `.` and `source` sometimes with slightly different semantics.

You'll also want to make sure you use `.` / `source` on `loadScripts.sh`. Doing `./loadScripts.sh` would start a new shell to interpret the script so define those functions in that short-lived shell, not in the invoking shell.

Also make sure a `/` is included in the path passed to `.` / `source`, for instance by running `. ./loadScripts.sh` if in the current working directory, otherwise its path is or may be¹ looked up in `$PATH`.

Doing `find... | while read...; do . ...; done` is wrong, first because of all the reasons noted at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697), but also here because in several shells including `bash` when the `lastpipe` option is not enabled, the `while` loop would be run in a subshell, so the functions in the sourced files would only be defined in that subshell.

If you wanted to use `find`, but beware `find` doesn't sort the list of files and includes hidden files, with `bash` 4.4 or above, you'd do:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 script; do
  . "$script"
done 3< <(LC_ALL=C find scripts/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sh' -type f -print0)
```

Here adding a `-type f` (to restrict to files of type *regular*) to justify the use of `find`.

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could just do:

```
for script (scripts/*(ND.)) . $script
```

As an equivalent (where `.` restricts to regular files, and `D` includes hidden ones).

Or:

```
for script (scripts/*(ND.)) emulate sh -c '. $script'
```

If those scripts are meant to be in `sh` syntax as the `.sh` extension suggests.

---

<sup>¹ bash's behaviour in that regard varies whether the `posix` option is enabled or not.</sup>

Comment: Not working. After running `loadScripts.sh` if I call `isApi` I get `isApi: command not found`.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, you'd also need to source that `loadScripts.sh` (with `. /path/to/loadScripts.sh` or `. ./loadScripts.sh` if in the current directory), if you intend those functions to be defined in the current shell. With just `./loadScripts.sh` or `bash ./loadScripts.sh` the functions are only defined in the new shell that is started to interpret that script.

Comment: I just copied your first code into my `loadScripts.sh` file and ran it `./loadScripts.sh`. It does not have a function in it. It only contains your script. But I get `line 2: syntax error near unexpected token .'

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, my bad, I forgot the `do`. See edit. Again, note you need `. ./loadScripts.sh`, not `./loadScripts.sh`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.